# Remove older $_GET from url

Tags: url, get, href

I've got some problems with my url on my website. I'm trying to get a link with the given GET parameters, but i'm getting my previous parameter aswell.

**My url looks like this:**

www.cdwinkel.dev/search-results?genre=Pop&medium=DVD&medium=Single .

**It should be:**

www.cdwinkel.dev/search-results?genre=Pop&medium=Single .

I'm running the following code:

```
$data['url'] = createurl();   

function createurl(){
    $i = 1;
    $string = "?";
    $keys = array_keys($_GET);
    foreach($_GET as $get){
        if($get != ""){
        $string .= $keys[$i] . "=" . $get ."&";
        $i++;
        }
    }
    $string = rtrim($string, "&");
    return $string;
}
```

$i = 1, because my first value in my array is empty.

And my button looks like this:

```
<a href='".$data['url'].'&medium='.$names[$i]."'>
```

I guess I should'nt set **&medium=.$names[$i]** in the href tag, 
but I wont get the new $names[$i] in my function, so I won't get a new url if i wont add it in.

I'm looking forward to your responce.

Sincerely,
Kars Takens

Comment: Put your parameters into an array, and then use [`http_build_query`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php) instead of your self-written function (which is seriously lacking, because it does not handle URL-encoding properly.)

Comment: I've tried this, but i'm getting a wierd return. i guess this is happening because i'm creating my array at the wrong way. My input array looks like:                 0 => 'genre' => 'jazz'', 1 => 'medium' => 'LP''. And it should be                  genre => jazz. But i cant get this done

Comment: Well then build your input array the right way to begin with …?

Comment: i got the right array atm. but i still got the same problem with the double parameters.

Comment: Why, do you have those doubles in your array? You should probably show some current code.

Answer (score 0):

At this point i've created an array with the right arraykeys and values.

```
 $url = array_slice($_GET, 1);
```

This returns the following array:

```
array (size=2)
    'genre' => string 'Pop' (length=3)
    'medium' => string 'DVD' (length=3)
```

After this I decoded this into a new string:

```
genre=Pop&medium=DVD
```

I got 6 button which I created in a foreach loop, but i'm getting &medium='VALUE' Twice. This only happens after the first time. So the first time my button works well.

```
<?php
$names = array_keys($data['tellen']);
$i = 0;
foreach($data['tellen'] as $m){
     echo "<li><a href='search-results?".$data['url'].'&medium='.$names[$i]."'>". $names[$i] ." <span class='product-amount'>(". $m[0]->count. ")</span></a></li>";
     $i++;
}
```

Hopefully you can help me further with this information.

I solved my problem by adding this in my forloop:

```
foreach($data['tellen'] as $m){
if(isset($_GET['medium'])){
     unset($_GET['medium']);
     $url = array_slice($_GET, 1);
     $data['url'] = urldecode(http_build_query($url));
     }
echo "<li><a href='search-results?".$data['url'].'&medium='.$names[$i]."'>". $names[$i] ." <span class='product-amount'>(". $m[0]->count. ")</span></a></li>";
    $i++;
}
```